# J-K Flip Flop and Toggle

Tags: flipflop

While investigating the design of J-K Flip Flop, I cannot get my head around how toggle work. I know it only toggle as the clock goes from 0 to 1.

Here's my false understanding of how the toggle works.

Assume it's `Q = 0, Q' = 1`, and `J = K = 1`. Now the clock goes up, the detectors picks it up, and send an impulse.

The next state is `Q = 1, Q' = 1`, and that's nowhere near `Q = 1, Q' = 0`. Worse, as `J = K = 1` and clock stays high so no impulse is sent, it actually oscillate between `00` and `11`.

What's wrong with my understanding?

I'm simulating the one constructed by 4 NAND, and next state is determined by the following equations:

```
 Anext = not (Clock and J and Q')
 Bnext = not (Clock and K and Q )
 Qnext = not (  Q'  and A)
Q'next = not (  Q   and B)
```

Answer (score 1):

JK latch truth table

```
J   K   Qnext   Comment

0   0   Q       No change

0   1   0       Reset

1   0   1       Set

1   1   Q       Toggle
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake here is that you are treating `Q` and `Q'` as two separate variables or states. There is *only one* bit of storage, represented by `Q`. When we refer to `Q'`, it is defined as `Q' = NOT Q`, meaning it is always derived from the value of `Q`. As soon as `Q` changes from 0 to 1 in your example, `Q'` changes from 1 to 0.